# How to prevent or queue calls to the JBoss server before it finishes initializing everything?

Tags: jboss, ejb

I have an EAR I deploy on JBoss. This EAR contains two main components, a set of EJBs, and a servlet. It also contains several other libraries.

In the current state of the code, there is a need to initialize some singletons so that the EJB can actually work. This init is made in the servlet, to start all data caches and initialize them. My problem is that because of this separate initialization, which can last up to 30 seconds, there is a moment during which the EJB are deployed and available, but calling them would lead to errors.

So the question is: **is there a way to lock the EJB calls for the time of this initialization by the other component?** Ideally, it would just queue them and execute them once the init finished, but it could also refuse them.

The only way I can think of for now would be to have a static boolean in the initializer, which would be checked in the EJB calls (their interceptor, actually). But this is far from convenient. So I'm wondering if there is another way to do it, less dirty.